# 'His studies' in Latin

Tags: classical-latin, english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

The full sentence is 'Quintus no longer enjoyed his studies,' and I've translated it as 'Quintus non longior gaudebat studiorum.' Should 'studiorum' be genitive since it expresses possession?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer the main question, no—the *owner* goes into the genitive case, not the thing being owned. It's like the *'s* in English: you say *Quintus's studies*, with "Quintus" getting the special marker. So if you wanted to be very explicit about whose studies they are, you could say *studia Quintī*. You could also use the possessive adjective *suus -a -um* "their own": *studia sua* "his own studies".

But in this sentence, I don't think I'd use any sort of genitive or pronoun there. In English, almost every noun needs to have a *determiner*: a word like "the" or "a" or "his" or "that" that comes before it. Latin, on the other hand, doesn't. So while you can say specifically "these studies", or "his own studies", you don't have to; in many cases, I would just ignore the English determiner when translating, because the context already makes it obvious that these are *Quintus's* studies, not anyone else's.

---

You have a few other issues in that sentence, too. *Non longior* is "no longer" in the sense of "not having a greater length", not in the sense of "previously but not now"; I would recommend *non jam* instead. *Gaudeō* is closer to "rejoice" than "enjoy", so I'd replace that with something like *fruor*. And either way, the object of that verb should be in the ablative. But these are separate from the main thing you're asking about.

Comment: `non jam`? Isn't it `non iam` since J didn't exist in latin?

Comment: @MartinW Classical Latin had a few different instances where two sounds were written with the same letter; nowadays, people tend to use different letters for those, for clarity (i/j, u/v, a/ā, etc). For some reason i/j is less commonly written that way than the rest but I prefer to use it to make the pronunciation clear.